# how to properly create a rest method using dto

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, dto

I need to send a request to a third-party service, then get an object from the response and display it on the browser.

package com.statusinfonew.springboot.controller;

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.val;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.statusinfonew.springboot.model.ParamsPays;
import com.statusinfonew.springboot.service.dto.OpenJsonFormat;

@Controller
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    
    RestTemplate restTemlate;
    
    
    @GetMapping({"/"})
    public String showGeneralPage(Model model) {
                    model.addAttribute("general", "Welcome to App");
                return "hello";
        
    }

      @GetMapping(path = "/go")
      public List<ParamsPays> getInfoError(@RequestParam(value="token") String token, 
                             @RequestParam(value="orderId")String orderId){
        final String url =String.format("https://exemple.ru/payment/rest/getOrderStatus.do? 
        token=%s&orderId=%s", token, orderId);
                     OpenJsonFormat dto =restTemlate.getForObject(url, OpenJsonFormat.class);       
                     return Collections.singletonList(toModel(dto));
    }
            
    private ParamsPays toModel(OpenJsonFormat dto) {
      return new ParamsPays();
    }

package com.statusinfonew.springboot.service.dto;

import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;
        
    @Data
    public class OpenJsonFormat {
     @JsonProperty("actionCode")
     private String actionCode;
     @JsonProperty("amount")
     private String amount;
     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
     private Date date;
    }
```

When I enter a get request, an error is issued:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

http://localhost:8080/go?token=sdwggvpa0k4ponpkt9&orderId=6afsf0-a0bc-7ffd-a9a8-790d4s179

Wed Apr 21 21:26:35 SAMT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

I understand that I am making a gross mistake. Please help me figure it out

Comment: Its highly likely that you have context after port and before /go. Could you please post what you have on top of the class also?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: RequestParam orderId is missing in the URL that you pasted?

Comment: I said this as an example. The texture is so correct from the service that the api provides. Maybe there is a problem in the method itself. I do not know how to correctly send a third-party service request.

Comment: Have u tried debugging? Also where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Definitely need some more information - eg server logs, stack trace etc. Right now we don't know what the error is so resolving it is going to be very, very difficult. If in doubt with SO questions, it's better to include too much info rather than the opposite

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2021-04-23T16:42:25.583+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/go"
}

Comment: up cooment, Responce  json  who comes

Comment: it is logging: [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause